# Ubuntu unrar problem. Need help!

Tags: command-line, rar

I have installed unrar and rar binaries. I wanted to extract an archive:

```
root@vps1129135:/home/mc/plugins# unrar e plugins.rar

UNRAR 3.91 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Alexander Roshal

plugins.rar is not RAR archive
No files to extract
```

Comment: Maybe the tool is right and the archive `plugins.rar` actually ISN'T a valid .rar archive? Have you tried using other tools on other systems? Just to confirm that your input file isn't broken.

Comment: It might be helpful to expand on what the plugins.rar file is and where it came from... as per previous comment, your error suggests it's a broken rar, but that could be because the source is broken or because it's been corrupted.  Someone else can perhaps check if it's a public download.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `plugins.rar` is corrupt, and doesn't look like a "`RAR archive`". See what your system thinks the file is with `file plugins.rar`. Re-get the file, lather, rinse, repeat.